# How to make 2 POST request from a react form

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have made a react form and want to make a post request to webhook.site with the form data. If I receive a 200 status code then I want to send the form data to a backend express server for further operation.
I am using axios to make the POST request.
This is the axios snippet from my react form:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form = () => {
  const [candidate, setCandidate] = useState({
    fullName: "",
    phoneNumber: 0,
    email: "",
    gitProfile: "",
    linkToResume: "",
    designation: "",
    interest: "",
  });

  const onChange = e =>
    setCandidate({ ...candidate, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/", {
        candidate,
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res, candidate);
      });
  };
```

Currently i am directly sending data to the backend. I have individually checked posting to both the webhook.site and backend, the code is working fine. But I want to do it simultaneously. If I get a 200 status code after posting to webhook.site, then only I want to send the form data to backend.

Answer (score 1):

```
    axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/", {
    candidate,
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res, candidate);
   // Write your another post request here because if your first request return 200 statusCode  it will execute this function otherwise it will go catch function

  }).catch(error => { 
   // if your first request failed then it execute this function. Here you can get error message.
   console.log(error);  
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if first POST return status 200, then call next request.

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:5000/", {
    candidate,
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res, candidate);
    if (res.status === 200) {
      axios.post('/url', {data})
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: When I am sending the data to the backend it throws an error "Cannot read property of undefined".

Comment: The data in the second axios call should be enclosed in {}. {data}. Other than this it is working fine. Thank you

Comment: Yes you are right, there where missing braces. Happy it helps :).